# Notification between Javascript objects

Tags: javascript

if we have 2 Javascript Objects, how do we make them communicate.  For e.g. if a value changes in 1 object, how to notify the other object)

Comment: Take a look at mutation observers

Comment: I’d rather use [Proxies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) here.

Answer (score 2):

One way would be to add method to the observable object and set value of desired property through this method (setter if you will). This setter method would accept a value and a callback which would be executed each time the setter is called.

That callback function would then take list of observers and possibly execute some code related to them.

```js
const observable = {
  prop: 1,
  setProp(val, cb) {
    console.log(`value of "prop" has been set to ${val}`);
    this.value = val;
    cb();
  }
};

const observer1 = {
  name: 'observer1',
  notifyMe() {
    console.log(`${this.name} has been notified`);
  }
};

const observer2 = {
  name: 'observer2',
  notifyMe() {
    console.log(`${this.name} has been notified`);
  }
};

// callback for setter method
function notifyObservers(...observers) {
  observers.forEach((obs) => {
    obs.notifyMe();
  });
}

// set value of observable and pass callback which will then
// be executed
observable.setProp(2, () => {
  notifyObservers(observer1, observer2);
});
```

Same thing can be achieved using proxies and reflection.

```js
const observable = {
  prop: 1
};

const observer = {
  name: 'observer',
  notifyMe() {
    console.log(`${this.name} has been notified`);
  }
};

const proxy = new Proxy(observable, {
  set(target, prop, val) {
    console.log(`value of "${prop}" has been set to ${val}`);
    observer.notifyMe();
    return Reflect.set(target, prop, val);
  }
});

proxy.prop = 2;
```

The difference between the first example and this one is that here we are calling `notifyMe` each time some property of the observed object is being set, while in the previous example we were notifying observer only when `prop` was being set.

The same can be achieved, while using proxy, by wrapping `observer.notifyMe` part in if-statement checking for specific property name, such as `if (prop === 'prop') { observer.notifyMe() }`.

Comment: Thanks, at least I have some ideas now. I can explore more on this topic now !!